# edit mode view mode in web application

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications

Often we have a lot of pages that sometimes should be available in view mode and sometimes in edit mode. And what is worse, sometimes only some fields of those should be editable.

Are there any design patterns and best practices for this? One solution is to create 2 pages - one for view, one for edit. Another is to apply css style to make all inputs look like normal non-editable text. Are there any other, better ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't go with your two pages approach. Let's make an example, you have 10 fields on the page. For different requests(e.g. different user permission, roles, or other functionalities), you may render a page that contains different set of editable fields.

```
request1, field 1,2,3 should be editable
request2, field 2,3 should be editable
request3, field 3,6,7 should be editable
...
```

how would you handle this in your multi-pages approach?

I would make a list at server side, containing the fields (names for example) that need to be shown as editable.

In your jsp, when you print the fields, you check if the field is in that list, if true, display it as editable, otherwise as readonly.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In our application, the editor elements on the page have a "read only" property and they modify the DOM accordingly. So you get a `span` (or whatever the component uses in read only mode) or an `input` element when the component is editable.

On the server, this is controlled with a DSL which defines what object type you edit, which fields you can see at all and in which mode each field is.

The whole app is a based on [ZK](http://www.zkoss.org/) because that allows it pretty easily to replace parts of the DOM from Java code.